# Tensorflow RNN for classification with single output

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create a RNN in Tensorflow that classifies short texts analyzing them on per-letter basis. For that I created a numpy 2D array, where each piece of text was either padded or truncated, where each element is a character code. An output is just vector of clasess represented as one-hot encoded numpy 2D-array.

Here is an example:

```
train_x.shape, train_y.shape
```

> ((91845, 50), (91845, 5))

Input consists of 90K rows 50 chars each, output is 90K rows with 5 classes. Next, I want to build a network shown in a figure below.

[image: Network]

The structure looks trivial, but I deffinetelly lack knowledge in Tensorflow and run in all kinds of problems trying to at least do training. Here is the part of code I use to build the network

```
chars = sequence_categorical_column_with_identity('chars', params['domain_size']+1)
chars_emb = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(chars, dimension=10)
columns = [chars_emb]

input_layer, sequence_length = sequence_input_layer(features, columns)

hidden_units = 32
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_units, state_is_tuple=True)
rnn_outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, 
                                      inputs = input_layer,
                                      sequence_length=sequence_length,
                                      dtype=tf.float32)

output = rnn_outputs[:,-1,:]
logits = tf.layers.dense(output, params['n_classes'], activation=tf.nn.tanh)
# apply projection to every timestep.
# Compute predictions.
predicted_classes = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Compute loss.

loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels, logits=logits)
# Compute evaluation metrics.
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                               predictions=predicted_classes,
                               name='acc_op')
```

But I get an error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 8 values, but the requested shape has 1
     [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, sequence_input_layer/chars_embedding/assert_equal/Const)]]
```

A fuller minimal example you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/planetA/b45aaa7ed92699a8b82fda80934a667d). Most likely you would need Tensorflow 1.8.0.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: See my own answer, other than that, the accuracy was quite bad. I did no find the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

now allows to train the network, but the results are underwhelming.